# $A.A^t$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Be $A$ a semidefinite nonnegative matrix. What kind of conclusions can we say about $A$ if $A.A^t$ is diagonal?

Same question when $A$ is binary matrix.

Thanks

Comment: The matrix $AA^T$ is always symmetric.

Comment: @Chou: $AA^T$ is _always_ meaningful (and is always square).

Comment: Sorry I made a typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your $A$ will $A^TA$ is in addition to $AA^T$ look at the singular value decomposition  $$AA^T = {\sigma_1}^2 e_1e_1^T+ \sigma_2^2 e_2e_2^T + \cdots +\sigma_r^2 e_re_r^T$$ where $e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_r$ is the standard basis and $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \cdots \ge \sigma_r > 0$ are the singular values of $A$
makes $AA^T$
diagonal.

suppose the spectral decomposition of $$A^TA ={\sigma_1}^2 u_1u_1^T+ \sigma_2^2 u_2u_2^T + \cdots +\sigma_r^2 u_ru_r^T $$ where $u_1 = {1 \over \sigma_1}A^Te_1,\  u_2={1 \over \sigma_2}A^Te_2, \cdots$ are an orthonormal vectors.

then $$A = \sigma_1 e_1u_1^T+\sigma_2 e_2u_2^T + \cdots + \sigma_re_ru_r^T$$ and certainly depends on $u_1, u_2, \cdots$ and not necessarily diagonal.

Answer (score 4):

When $A$ is a nonnegative matrix, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $AA^T$ is diagonal
2. The *rows* of $A$ are mutually orthogonal
3. Each *column* of $A$ contains at most one nonzero entry.

$1\Leftrightarrow 2$ and $3\Rightarrow 2$ are obvious (and don't depend on $A$ being nonnegative).

For $2\Rightarrow 3$: A column with two nonzero entries would contribute their product to the inner product of the two rows in question, and when everything is nonnegative, there would be no way to cancel that out afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If $AA^T$ is diagonal, then the rows of $A$ are all mutually orthogonal.  I don't think we get anything out of the fact that $A$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

$(AB)^t = B^t A^t$ so $AA^t$ is always symmetric

Comment: Sorry i made a typo

Comment: @JMoravitz: It was an answer when it was posted. The question was edited afterwards..

Comment: Automated comment generated from review queue, wasn't a much more appropriate button to press than "this doesn't quite answer the question."  Even so, it is recommended to rethink the answer or remove.

Comment: @JMoravitz: When no other button is appropriate, "Skip" always is.

Comment: @JMoravitz: By default, "No comment needed"  is selected.  When none of the generic comments is applicable, you may recommend for deletion without posting one of them.  You can also type an appropriate comment yourself if you want.